# Entire Application in Django server shuts down with single error

Tags: django

I am new to Python and django , I worked on C# and php as developer earlier. My problem here is Entire Application in Django shuts down with single error.

for example i start my website with "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" example:-- i have two pages home and register
1) if i make error in register page code(register.py) , It shuts down home page too. Is there a way to prevent that as in php and C# in both one page do not effect other.
2) how to work in django with team one errors full team hangs.

3) How to work with live working websites things may become too risky.

also i am not able to find article related to this. kindly help

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be running a non local setup using manage.py. Please refer to Django Deployment guide available here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/

In general it recommends running Django behind uwsgi or gunicorn or something similar. A la php-fpm for php.

Also error in php will also kill the process if you run php php-file. Which you are essentially doing here.

Comment: from php i mean codeigniter ,and c# i mean MVC pattern . 
Can we have same here in django.

Comment: Please read the tutorial on Django website and follow it. Don't run your app without a web server.